How to write verify for static methods that have been called [in Mockito Core]
Without using PowerMockito and using Mockito-Core (the version of Mockito doesn't support PowerMockito and I cannot change the Mockito version), How can I verify that a call to a static method has been made?
try(mockedStatic<Property> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(Property.class)){
    mockedStatic.when(() -> Property.getProperty("Config")).thenReturn(true);
    injectMockedClass.mymethod(attribute) //The Actual Call
}

This is how I have mocked the Static Class. How can I verify the getProperty() method of static Property class was called?

does verify() not worked? mockedStatic.verify(() -> Property.getProperty("Config"));
